# Can anyone help me figure out how this text animation works?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I fell in love with the text animation effect (on thumbnails hover) in this demo https://2joomla.net/wordpress/wordpress-gallery-demo-1/, but sadly I cannot figure out how it works.

I've just spent something like 4 hours try to find something on google. I've tried combining `lettering.js` with the following jQuery but nothing:

```
$('.IconAnimate i').each(function(i) {
  $(this).css('opacity', 0);
  $(this).delay(1000 * i).animate({
    'opacity': 1.0
  }, 450);
});
```

How can I obtain the bold-zooonscale-wave-ish effect in the demo page?

Answer (score 0):

Each letter is contained in a div with this code:

```
<div style="position: relative; display: inline-block; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);">D</div>
```

and all thous divs are in a main div that gets displayed on mouseover... check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp) it'll point you in the right direction I think.